# Quartz+Hibernate: simple util eats memory. What could be wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

**EDIT: I found the answer to the memory leak myself, and posted it along with the others. If someone can answer why I have to do apply the fix at all (see question in my answer), I will gladly award the answer :-) **

I wrote a simple util that periodically reads log files and saves the entries to a database. Not much code and seemingly works fine. But after running it on a big lump of logs today I found that it was not production ready ...  After the first job was finished chewing through all of the logs, the next 15 jobs would fire off, until no more connections could be established and the next job would fail with a SqlException. For the next five hours the app spewed out exceptions unnoticed until running out of memory.

The job was set up using the following cron trigger, "* */2 * * * ?", which means "run every two minutes". The weird thing is that after the first job was finished (which took approx. an hour) the remaining jobs would fire rapidly, one after another. This was unexpected, as I would think there had to be two minutes between each job.

Now I wonder what could be wrong. I am guessing the reason is either in how I am using Hibernate and/or Quartz. Maybe I am not releasing the session as I should, or have misunderstood how Quartz schedules jobs?Or maybe I should inject the Hibernate factory into to the job, and not create it in each job? getCurrentSession() vs openSession()? No idea. I still do not understand why this should have any effect, as the jobs should release all resources on exit. Anyway, most of the relevant code is to be seen below.

No matter if I get the connection problem sorted, the code is suffering from some sort of memory leak. It is as if every job executed is somehow kept on the heap. By executing

`java -Xmx17M -DcronTriggerExpression="*/1 * * * * ?" -jar myjar.jar`,

I can force the problem to appear by running the program with a minimal amount of memory. It just takes four consecutive runs in this case before I get a OutOfMemoryError when building the session factory for hibernate.

```
public class ExportJob implements Job {
    LogImporter importer;

    public ExportJob() { //needed for Quartz 
        setUpHibernate(); 
        importer = new LogImporter(); //injected, but this saves space on SO :)
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        /* even if this body is empty, I get a OutOfMemoryError */        
    }

    private SessionFactory setUpHibernate() {
        logger.debug("Setting up hibernate");
        this.sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the rapid firing is caused by Quartz.  It's queuing up jobs every 2 minutes, so after one hour you should have 59 jobs itching to start.

You are right, closing the SessionFactory, not the session fixes the problem.  That also explains running our of Connections, just to close the loop - and hopefully get an award ;-).  Although Hibernate allows multiple SessionFactory, each one will maintain a Connection.

From their documentation:

> When all mappings have been parsed by the
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration, the application must obtain a factory
>   for org.hibernate.Session instances. This factory is intended to be
>   shared by all application threads. Hibernate does allow your
>   application to instantiate more than one org.hibernate.SessionFactory.
>   This is useful if you are using more than one database.

So the final fix should be to create one SessionFactory elsewhere and reuse it to generate sessions in each thread, or job in this case.

Comment: I already do session.close(): it's in the finally block, which is always executed.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Quartz, BTW.

Comment: You were close, though :) Needed to close the sessionfactory as well.

Comment: Good work on solving that.  I wonder if you would be better off creating the SessionFactory outside the job and injecting it?  Seems like creating it every time might be a lot of overhead.

Comment: That's what I thought too, and I actually did that some time after posting this. The reason I did not do it in the first place was that I was unaware that the JobMap could contain something else than strings. But it worked perfectly fine with a session factory as well. And as a bonus, I don't have to explicitly close the sessions factory in the job.

Comment: giving you the award, even though I am still unsure why GC is not picking up the session factory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but it almost sounds like you want the job to run sequentially every 2 minutes. If that's the case, you might want to implement [StatefulJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html) instead of Job. This way, you can ensure the running concurrent jobs will not tie up all the database connections.

Comment: Did not help, though ... I think the first problem to solve is my memory leak.

Comment: Are you saying if you comment out the entire `while` loop in `execute(..)`, you are still getting OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: By using `StatefulJob`, do you still get `SqlException`? If so, what's the exception message?

Comment: Hi there, limc. Thanks for returning :) I changed my code to use StatefulJob - no change. Still run out. But I found a fix! See my answer below. Not quite sure why it is needed though ... Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

From your first version of post , I notice the following code :

```
 for (LogEntry logEntry : newEntries) {
        session.save(logEntry);
        ...................
}
```

Every time you save a new logEntry , it will be persisted in the hibernate Session. Every persistent object is placed into the  first level cache (your JVM's memory)  and will not be CG . So , if you save many logEntry in transaction , you may run into the memory exhaustion . You should flush and clear the hibernate session to release some memory after saving certain number of objects  .Refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts) for the best practice of batch insert using hibernate

BTW , you set the maximum heap size only to 17MB ,which is so small that your application can easily run out of memory before the real problematic code runs .So , `OutOfMemoryError` may due to the codes inside the while-loop .

I suggest you to take the heap dump when `OutOfMemoryError` occurs  .Then examining  the heap dump to see which instances are suspected to cause the memory leak . You can refer [this](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) on how to use the  **VisualVM**  to collect and analysis the heap dump.

Comment: the 17MB were just used to demonstrate the problem. this is the minimum memory plus some. I could set it to 30MB or 100MB. Even with an empty method body, I would still run out of memory.

It turned out that I needed to explicitly close the SessionFactory after use. Why that is not handled by GC is beyond me.

Comment: Good point about caching, though! And thanks for the link on batch inserts.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to close the SessionFactory after use. If I did not, the session factories would be kept in memory for some reason. So simply adding a `sessionFactory.close()` at the end of `execute()` did the trick. No more OutOfMemoryError.

Now *why* I have to do that is beyond me: I thought that usual Java rules still applied. When the job is no longer running (Quartz probably nulling it), all the dependent objects are garbage collected (including the SessionFactory). That should have released its resources. Or so I thought?